# How to Create a Mutex for a Single Instance Python Application

Tags: python, instance, mutex

I have been using the following recipe to only allow a single instance of my application:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474070-creating-a-single-instance-application/

The recipe uses a "mutexname" variable which is filled with some mutex value. If I want to create my own unique "mutex", how do I do it? Also, how does this recipe work? Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipe uses the win32 api function [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a named mutex. A mutex is a system object and exists outside your app's process. GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS when CreateMutex is called with a name that already exists. The recipe checks for this return value and exits if so. You should change the recipe to use a different string for mutexname. Pick something that is unlikely for some else to lock on because if they do your application won't be able to start.

Comment: Can the string be of any value or length? Also, does it have to be ascii characters, or can it be made up of bytes as well?

Comment: I don't really know what distinction you're trying to make between "ascii characters" and "bytes". In Python 2.x, there are two kinds of things that can be called a string: `str`, which is really a sequence of bytes, and `unicode`, which is a sequence of characters (Unicode code points). The recipe shows the use of `str`, since the Windows API is non-Unicode by default. The windows API documentation for `CreateMutex` claims: "The name is limited to MAX_PATH characters and can contain any character except the backslash path-separator character (\). Name comparison is case sensitive."

Comment: I was using similar code in Python 2.7, now with Python 3.7 I don't get the ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS error. Anyone has the same issue?